# OpenShift - deployed application doesn't load scripts/links from the header tag

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, openshift

I've deployed a simple NodeJS application serving a static page, to OpenShift.

My server.js source code looks like this -

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var ip = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || "127.0.0.1";
var port = process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_PORT || 8080;

//Creating static route for index.html resources @ /static/img
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/static/img'));

//GET for index.html
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/static/index.html')); 
});

app.listen(port, ip, function() {
    console.log((new Date()) + ": Server is running on port 8080");
});
```

The scripts in my index.html's `<head>` looks like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <link href="http://pingendo.github.io/pingendo-bootstrap/themes/default/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

This runs completely fine as expected on my local system, but somehow the JS/CSS doesn't seem to load on the OpenShift application. There are no local CSS files that I'm using - everything is pulled by the head scripts. Debug logs don't show anything unusual either, and I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer is here:
https://forums.openshift.com/pictures-css-where-can-i-store-resources

Accordingly I modified to the standard openshift created server.js for node.js server configuration:

```
self.start = function() {
    ...
    // added >>
    self.app.use('/', express.static(__dirname+'/'));
    //modify the list of directories as needed
    ['css', 'img', 'js', 'i18n', 'lib'].forEach(function (dir){
        self.app.use('/'+dir, express.static(__dirname+'/'+dir));
    });
    // << added
};
```